# Should I use htmlspecialchars inside <a> tag

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

The title says it all.

Should I include `htmlspecialchars();` function inside `<a>` tag?

Thanks

Comment: For the href tag ? No. See urlencode(). (edit : no i didn't vote down)

Comment: if you down vote this question, at least say why

Comment: The question is why you want to use it? Whats the data looks like?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use it? The question is waaay too vague and open to interpretation. Use it **where exactly** "inside `<a>` tag"? For the URL? For the text content? For an attribute?

Comment: i have this code: <a href="/post/<?php echo urlencode($next_title); ?>/<?php echo $next_id; ?>"> and I want to know if I need to use htmlspecialchars(); to "save" from xss attack

Comment: @user3774526 Again where you want to use it?

Comment: inside the href attribute and title attribute. I am asking if it's neccesary to use it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` is a function to escape certain characters which have a special meaning in HTML. For example, if you wanted to embed a value which contains quotes inside an HTML attribute:

```
<a title="Simon says "Hello World"">
```

This obviously breaks the HTML syntax. You need to apply the escaping function to the value `Simon says "Hello World"` to arrive at:

```
<a title="Simon says &quot;Hello World&quot;">
```

This is now correct HTML syntax.

The same goes for values containing `<` or `>` in regular text, because those can obviously be interpreted as HTML tags. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for more on the topic.

You need to do this the same way for *all* HTML tags and values.

```
printf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
       htmlspecialchars($url),
       htmlspecialchars($title),
       htmlspecialchars($content));
```

URLs have their own escaping rules, you may have to URL encode values you put into a URL before you put it into HTML:

```
$url = sprintf('/foo/%s', urlencode($bar));
printf('<a href="%s">...</a>', htmlspecialchars($url));
```